# Java Controlled loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, do-while

so I wanted to do a controlled loop using java (I'm a beginner), it's basically a loop with no specific limit until the user inputs a specific number then the loop ends, so I created an array and put it in a loop and wanted the user to input as much numbers as they want until they press 0 then the loop breaks:

```
int[] n = new int[100]; // maximum size of the array is a 100
int i=0, counter = 0;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Type your "+(i+1)+" age and end with 0: ");
    n[i] = userInput.nextInt();
    i++;
    counter++;
} while (n[i] != 0);

// only print the first 10 ages
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)  {
    System.out.println("The " + (i+1) +" age is " + n[i]);
}
```

The output is the console asking me to input the first number and then cracks and prints counter lines (Goes to the other loop)

Comment: umm.. so.. the question is? btw, you can have `while(true)` paired with `break` to exit the endless loop. you can use `ArrayList` or any `List` implementation to have arbitrary number of inputs.

Comment: The question is that i want to do a controlled loop ended with typing 0 but something is wrong with my implementation and i need a fix

Comment: I suggest you add some print statements to help debug!

Comment: *" ... something is wrong with my implementation and ... "*.  How do you know that something is wrong?  Is it throwing an exception?  (Show us the stacktrace).  Is it producing the wrong output?  (Explain what output you are getting and what you are expecting to get.)  This question really needs a [minimal reproducible example](/minimal-reproducible-example).   But at the very least, you should make the >>Question<< clear so that people don't have to guess what you are actually asking.  And include all relevant evidence ...

Comment: @StephenC I feel the OP's final sentence describes accurately what's going wrong.  I'm not sure what other information you could possibly need.

Comment: To me, that last line is unintelligible.  Sorry ... but maybe you are better at understanding poor English than me.  Either way, it is unclear.  And either way, the OP needs to learn the requirements for "help me debug my code" questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You're incrementing `i` before the while loop tests the condition.  That is, you're always incrementing `i` to point to a value in the array that is after the value you just stored.

When you initialize an array as you have, the default value for every index in the array is 0, which matches your loop's exit condition.